# normalizing from the range -1 and 1 to range 0 and 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am not mathematician so please dont get mad if my question is simple:

I have some numbers between -1 and 1 but I want to normalize them between 0 and a positive number. I am wondering what approach should I take?

Extra information: I have some numbers as follow :
0.0 -0.0025 0.0 4.0E-4 0.0 -0.0082 0.0 4.0E-4 0.0 2.0E-4 1.0E-4 3.0E-4

and I have these numbers in database I will read them and show them on a graph but unfortunately my graph just shows positive numbers so I need to somehow change my range to a positive range. If you need more information that you think I missed please let me know

More info: negative numbers show level of sadness and positive one show level of happiness so I should convert them in a way that the difference between the  level of happiness and sadness show itself

Comment: Why would we be mad at you?

Comment: It sounds like you are in an applied context. We would likely need to know the context in order to give good advice. Different purposes might lead to different solutions.

Comment: Great please see Extra info above:)

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ ranges from $-1$ to $1$, how about $y=\frac 12(x+1)$?  Does that meet your need?

Comment: Thanks but why do we need to divide it by 2?(I also added some extra info above)

Comment: @user2860721 if we just add $1$ the $1+x$ will be between $0$ and $2$, dividing by $2$ fits it into $0$ and $1$

Comment: You divide by $2$ because your starting range is of length $2$ and ending is of length $1$.  If we don't, the output will be $0$ to $2$

Comment: Since your range is not from $-1$ to $1$, let $min$ be the minimum value and $max$ be the maximum value.  You can do $y=\frac {x-min}{max-min}$ to always come out from $0$ to $1$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the extra info. So the data you display will be different from the data you read in. As long as that's clear, you could just take the absolute value of each number.

Edit: Given the (new) extra info, you don't want to just take the absolute value. The ${1\over 2}(x + 1)$ transformation will keep the happy/sad values separated.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few alternatives.

If you need to maintain the relative positions of the data $\displaystyle \frac{x+1}{2}$ is a sensible choice.

If your requirement is such that values near $0$ don't have much difference, but a small difference for values near $1$ and $-1$ is significant, $x^2$ would be a good idea. Try playing around with other even exponents, $x^4$ for example. The higher the power, the more pronounced the difference for input values near $1$ and $-1$ and the smaller the difference for input near $0$.

**EDIT**: Under your new happy/sad info, an alternative for $x^2$ would be $\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)^2$

In case you just need to adjust the range, but the sign doesn't mean anything, then $abs(x)$ or $|x|$ is a good choice.